# Inner join with composite key in spring data jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities as below which I want to use to fetch data from using spring data jpa. I am using H2 database for this purpose.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AccountCompositeKey.class)
@Data
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customerId")
    private int customerId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private UUID accountId;

    private String country;

    @OneToMany
    private List<AccountBalance> balance;
}
```

The other entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "account_balance")
@IdClass(AccountBalanceCompositeKey.class)
@Data
public class AccountBalance {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name="account_id")
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private UUID accountId;

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CurrencyEnum currency;

    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

I have created a JPA repository and I want to fetch values from both the tables by having a join on `account_id` column only.

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, AccountCompositeKey> {

    Account findByAccountId(UUID accountId);
}
```

I am running into issues when I am trying to call this `findByAccountId` method. Have I created the entities and mappings correctly? How should I be able to achieve the below SQL query equivalent using JPA?
`SELECT A.ACCOUNT_ID, A.AMOUNT, B.CUSTOMER_ID FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCE A JOIN ON ACCOUNT B WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID=?`

Comment: Why the annotation `@JoinColumn` at the field accountId ?

Comment: The account_balance table is joined using the account_id column which is acting as a foreign key